# Redirect to different domain if url contains "@ at" symbol

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Let's say I have the main domain blog.com and I want to add the feature so users can have short links for example:

`https://blog.com/@username` and this link should be redirected to `https://app.blog.com/profile/username`

How to make it possible? And is it enough just to use `.htaccess` or I have to use php for example `parse_url($url)`?

Comment: What is your sever framework (the answer will change depending what you are using)

Comment: I'm using Apache on WHM (cPanel). So I guess the only options I have is to use htaccess or not really the right way - php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file in the `blog.com` domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(blog\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^@([\w-]+)$ https://app.%1/profile/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The regex `[\w-]+` limits the `username` to the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen).

The `%1` backreference contains `blog.com` captured from the preceding *CondPattern* (saves repetition). And `$1` contains the *username* as captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

This is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then change to a 301, but only once you have confirmed this works as intended. (301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.)

The above assumes both `blog.com` and `app.blog.com` point to the same place on the filesystem (or somewhere on the same file-path). If not then the preceding *condition* is not required. In fact, the preceding condition is not strictly necessary anyway, since the resulting URL does not contain the `@` - so no redirect loop would occur anyway. So, the following is probably sufficient:

```
RewriteRule ^@([\w-]+)$ https://app.blog.com/profile/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Although this will also mean that `https://app.blog.com/@username` will also likely be redirected.

You can also do this using PHP, but that depends how you are currently routing URLs through your PHP application (if at all on your `blog.com` hostname).

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your time spent to write such a detailed response.